# Testcafe and Browserstack - Unable to find browser

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I run want to run tests on a jenkins server. Locally the same code and credentials work.

When i start the test-runner on the test-server i get:  *Unable to find the browser. "browserstack:chrome" is not a browser alias or path to an executable file.*

Before running the code the browserstack application is downloaded and started as described here: https://janmolak.com/jenkins-2-0-pipelines-and-browserstack-bd5a4ed3010d

I also tried this: '''./node_modules/.bin/testcafe -b browserstack'''
which also does work locally but fails on the jenkins server.

What could be the reason or how can i get more info about what happens?

Comment: did you run `npm i -g testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack` on your Jenkins box?

Comment: Once you had sucess with the above message, you need to specify what OS you want in browserstack. browserstack:Chrome@78:Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it solved itself, i use 'browserstack:Chrome@83.0:Windows 10' now.
Then it got stuck at browserstack because several requests make it really slow without feedback, i checked the browserstack dashboard and saw many requests running.

Comment: FYI you can pass 'browserstack:chrome:OS X' and it will run the latest version of Chrome on the latest OSX version. Same goes for all desktop browsers and OS, I specify desktop because mobile versions don't always run the latest in my experience.